# NAS4Free istallation from LiveUSB to USB: not working

Tags: installation, nas, freebsd, freenas, liveusb

I'm trying to install NAS4Free on my home server but I have some troubles.

There are several step-by-step instructions in the Internet, I used this one: http://www.mini-itx.com/projects/nas4free/?page=1 (others suggested the same steps).

In short there stated:

1. Download LiveUSB image file from sourceforge
2. Using Win32DiskImager create a bootable USB stick
3. Boot up the server
4. Once boot completed - insert the second USB stick
5. Pick 9 ("Install/Upgrade NAS4Free from LiveCD/LiveUSB")
6. Choose "Install 'Embedded' OS on CF/USB Flash Drive or Hard Drive"
7. Choose source

And now (after I picked the right source - the USB drive I just booted from) I faced with unexpected behaviour: instead of asking me for the destination drive - server returns to step 6 (see picture below):

[image]
*(My picture is not absolutely the same - but it is the same installation step)*

And so on. So server does not offering me to choose the destination. Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong?